# How to change layout height programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I try to change RelativeLayout height programmatically. I try to explain my problem: In my `activity.xml` file, I have header layout(top position) and I also have one layout in botton position. With a click, I try to change botton position layout's height(full screen - Top layout height).

Here is `activity.xml` code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/movies_title_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/headerimage" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gomoviewlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/slide_menu_image" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play_trailer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/play_trailer" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/popaplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/movie_info_shadow" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movies_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/movies_title"
        android:layout_below="@+id/movies_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descraption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is Java code:

```
popaplayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_description = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT-movies_header_layout.getWidth()  );

            popaplayout.setLayoutParams(layout_description);

        }
    });
```

**popaplayout** is the layout witch I try to change it's height.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Why are you doing  `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT-movies_header_layout.getWidth()`? Do you realize that the value of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` is always -1 right?

Comment: i try to change my popaplayout height.i mean.my popap layout should be bellow header layout

Comment: And what is the header layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your onClickListener:

```
((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)popaplayout.getLayoutParams()).addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.movies_title_layout);
```

This will make the view's top the same as the header's bottom